# Printing messages to a component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to write a component like the console where it prints one message after the other instead of replacing the old message.

Ideally what I want to do is have a component that I can print strings into like a chatbox using other parts of my program, and it will just keep scrolling down with the newly outputted strings, and you can scroll up to see the old strings. Either forever or once it reaches x amount of lines it will remove the oldest line.

```
1
2
3
2
1
2
```

How would I go about doing something like this? is there a component that lets me do something like this? I thought of just keep adding the new string onto the old one in my state and just displaying state but that sounds like it will take up a lot of unnecessary space and resources.

here is what I have tried, but all this is way too slow and I end up getting multiple messages on one line if I scroll too fast:

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            mainStr: ''
        };
        this.eventHandler.bind = this.eventHandler.bind(this);
    }

    eventHandler = (e) => {
        this.setState({ mainStr: (this.mainStr += '\n' + e.type.toString())})
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div onWheel={this.eventHandler}>
                PERFORM EVENTS HERE
                {this.state.mainStr}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

what I want is just an easier way to print these event messages on my page, preferably in some sort of chatbox like component and isn't as slow as updating state, i'm assuming there's a way to print it and not have to keep it in my state while still having it on the screen?

I know I am wording this very badly but I am not familiar with the terminology.

Comment: Please provide at least _some_ code to start of.

Comment: I don't know what code i can even provide, I just want something that does basically the same thing as console.log(this.state.xxx) except on the webpage not the console, where you can still the previous lines

Comment: Sorry, but this is the site rule. Show what you currently have which includes the `console.log(this.state.xxx)` and we can start from there. :)

Comment: ok i added some code to describe what I'm talking about, I want an easier way to print these event messages on my page, preferably in some sort of chatbox like component and isn't as slow as updating state, i'm assuming there's a way to print it and not having to keep it in my state while still having it on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

At least you need to store all these values into an array and display all the values in the render

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      mainStr: []
    };
    this.eventHandler.bind = this.eventHandler.bind(this);
  }

  eventHandler = (e) => {

    let newValue = e.type.toString(); // your new value

    this.setState({
      mainStr: [...this.state.mainStr, newValue)]
    })
  };

  render() {
      return ( <
        div onWheel = {
          this.eventHandler
        } >
        PERFORM EVENTS HERE {
          this.state.mainStr.map(str => < p > str < /p>)} <
            /div>
          );
        }
      }
```

Comment: do I need to keep track of the old messages? is there no way to do it so that once I print it I no longer have to keep track of it in my state?

Comment: So you want to display only an amount of lines that it ?